# How to capture the Excel Workbook open complete?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am opening huge workbook using excel interop and I need to save the workbook after opening completed why because after saving only my addin tab is getting enabled so I want to track the workbook open complete. Right now I handled this by inserting sleep in between opening and saving of workbooks.

Is there any better way to get the open complete in excel.

```
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName);      
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        wb.Save();
```

How to save the workbook after opening complete.

Here I assume that workbook completely opens in 5 seconds, but this is not a good solution. Can any one help me how to come out this problem?

Comment: Have you tried handling the [WorkbookOpen  Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.workbookopen(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thankx Conrad Frix , Yes I haven't tried but I am thinking the same will it work? When will th open call exactly?

Comment: The Workbook_open event fires immediately. If you want code to run AFTER the workbook is open, use the Workbook_Activate() event.

Comment: @sous2817 sounds you actually know that [WorkbookActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.workbookactivate(v=office.15).aspx) will work, as opposed to my guess of workbook open. Perhaps you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @ConradFrix I'm not entirely sure the poster has control over the incoming workbook, where they can add code to the event itself.  So for my idea to work, they'd have to put the workbook save in the Workbook_Activate() event in VBA and not C# code.  If the OP comes back and confirms how much control they have over the workbook being  opened by the code, I'll post a solution.